# How do I make textwrap print a variable along with some text?

Tags: python, tuples, wrapper, text-based

This is the code I'm using to make part of a text-based game:

```
armour = int(0)
message = "You have no weapons to fight with. The bokoblin hits you with its club (3 damage) but your armour 
reduces the damage (-",str(armour),") and you manage to escape."
wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=90)
words = wrapper.wrap(text=message)
for element in words:
  print(element)
```

I want to use textwrap to print the text without the words getting split at the end of a line, which works fine, but when I put a variable (armour) in the text it comes up with an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 126, in <module>
    intro()
  File "main.py", line 20, in intro
    left()
  File "main.py", line 47, in left
    fight()
  File "main.py", line 112, in fight
    words = wrapper.wrap(text=message)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/textwrap.py", 
line 351, in wrap
    chunks = self._split_chunks(text)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/textwrap.py", 
line 337, in _split_chunks
    text = self._munge_whitespace(text)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/textwrap.py", 
line 154, in _munge_whitespace
    text = text.expandtabs(self.tabsize)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'expandtabs'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I don't want to use \n instead of textwrap due to different monitor sizes.

Comment: Your `message` is a tuple because of `,`. You need to do something like `message = f"my string {armour} my other string"`

Comment: Thanks so much crissal I was stuck on that for ages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use variables in a string you have to use a `format` or `f` string.

```
count = 20
#string formatting versions
newest  = f'I have {count} apples left.'
older   = 'I have {} apples left.'.format(count)
ancient = 'I have %i apples left.' % count
```

[more...](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)